# 'Help' A column cannot be generated by the server

Tags: c#, linq

My Table Code

```
use master
go
create database Test01
go
use Test01
SET 
  ANSI_NULLS, 
  QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, 
  CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, 
  ANSI_WARNINGS, 
  ANSI_PADDING 
ON;
go
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GiangVien](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MaGV]  AS ('GV'+right('000000'+CONVERT([varchar](10),[ID]),(6))) PERSISTED NOT NULL primary key,
    [HoTenGV] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [NgaySinh] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [GioiTinh] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [DiaChi] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [MaKhoa] [varchar](7) NOT NULL,
)
```

when I use Linq to Insert A new Values this Message error was throw : 
The primary key column of type 'VarChar(8)' cannot be generated by the server.
What should I Do Now ?

Comment: You should make the ID the PK. Why are you trying to make the calculated column a PK?

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear: having a calculated column as primary key is not possible. Use the `[ID]` column as PK.
If you want efficient searching on `[MaGV]` then you can create an Index on that column (either clustered or non-clustered).

An alternative is to use this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GiangVien](
    [MaGV] VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    ....
```

And then calculate/generate the values yourself as you insert them. This would allow for Foreign Keys to point to this Primary Key.